# How to add listener for database changes in Hibernate?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, servlets

How can I add listener for row changes like insertion, updation, deletion in Hibernate.

Comment: have a look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JPA listeners `@PostUpdate`, `@PostPersist`, `@PostRemove` (these are portable across ORM frameworks) and you can look [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) for JPA spec.

> The PostPersist and postRemove callback methods are invoked for an
>   entity after the entity has been made persistent or removed.  These
>   callbacks will also be invoked on all entities to which these
>   operations  are  cascaded.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Hibernate Interceptors](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/events/Events.html). Here is an example to log updates (directly taken from the Hibernate documentation):

```
public static class LoggingInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Override
    public boolean onFlushDirty(
        Object entity,
        Serializable id,
        Object[] currentState,
        Object[] previousState,
        String[] propertyNames,
        Type[] types) {
            LOGGER.debugv( "Entity {0}#{1} changed from {2} to {3}",
                entity.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                id,
                Arrays.toString( previousState ),
                Arrays.toString( currentState )
            );
            return super.onFlushDirty( entity, id, currentState,
                previousState, propertyNames, types
        );
    }
}
```

But this will only work for changes inside the same application. Other changes are not tracked. If you need this, you should use database triggers.